# Scraping Issue. My loop doesn't keep going after error

Tags: python, css, arrays, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import string

try:
    for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
        URL = 'https://www.colonialzone-dr.com/'+c+'-dominicanismos-dictionary'
        page = requests.get(URL)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        main_div = soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "entry-content"})

        words = main_div.find_all("p")
        for word in words:
            print(word.text)
except:
    print("No Vocabulary Avaliable for " + c)
    pass
```

webpage for x doesn't exist so it stops but I want it to continue to get information for webpages of y and z

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `try/except` inside the loop.

```
for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
    URL = 'https://www.colonialzone-dr.com/'+c+'-dominicanismos-dictionary'
    try:
        page = requests.get(URL)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        main_div = soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "entry-content"})
        words = main_div.find_all("p")
        for word in words:
            print(word.text)
    except:
        print("No Vocabulary Avaliable for " + c)
```

Comment: The same one, it stopped after the w page, it didn't continue

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mehki/PycharmProjects/SideProjects/scrape.py", line 16, in <module>
    words = main_div.find_all("p")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: You should check whether `main_div` contains anything.

Comment: I assumed the error was with fetching the page. I've put the `try` around all the other code too.

Comment: But you could also use `if main_div:`

Answer (score 0):

Use try and except block inside `main_div` where it cant locate so it goes to except and print associate letter!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
for i in string.ascii_lowercase:
    html=requests.get("https://www.colonialzone-dr.com/"+i+"-dominicanismos-dictionary").text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    try:
        main_div = soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "entry-content"})
        words = main_div.find_all("p")
        for word in words:
            print(word.text)
    except:
        print("could not find for letter",i)
```